# Horizontal space between subcaptions

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats, subcaption

I have the next graphic

[image]

As you can see, the subcaption `(b)` is not centered from the corresponding subfigure like `(a)`. If I increase the value for `[.51\linewidth]` unwanted things happen. I'm using `subcaption` package with `memoir` because the native memoir tools for `subfigure`s show problems with flush right. The code for picture above is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{23cm}{15.9cm} 
\settrimmedsize{23cm}{15.9cm}{*} 
\settrims{0pt}{0pt} 
\settypeblocksize{17.8cm}{11.3cm}{*} 
\setlrmargins{2.3cm}{*}{*} 
\setulmargins{6.4\onelineskip}{*}{*} 
\setheadfoot{1.18\onelineskip}{\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{4.1\onelineskip}{*}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout[lines] 

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/area style/.style={%
area cycle list,
area legend,
axis on top,
}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\blindtext

\begin{figure}[b]
%\centering
\subcaptionbox{A cat\label{cat}}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.71]
 \begin{axis}[axis equal,axis on top,axis lines=center,enlargelimits=false,xlabel=$x(t)$,ylabel=$y(t)$,xmax=2.5,xmin=-2.2,ymax=2.5,ymin=-2.2,area legend,xtick=\empty,ytick= \empty %,legend entries={$\Ran f$}]
\addplot[draw=blue!30!white,fill=blue!30!white,
domain=-2:2,samples=120] {sqrt(4-x^2)};
%\addlegendimage{fill=blue!30!white,area legend}
%\addlegendentry{$\Ran f$}
\addplot[draw=blue!30!white,fill=blue!30!white,
domain=-2:2,samples=120] {-sqrt(4-x^2)};

\addplot[white,fill,
domain=-1:1,samples=120] {sqrt(1-x^2)};
\addplot[white,fill,
domain=-1:1,samples=120] {-sqrt(1-x^2)};
%\node at (380,170) {$x'(t)$};
%\node at (20,170) {$y'(t)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subcaptionbox{An elephant\label{elephant}}[.51\linewidth]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.71,/pgf/declare function={f=1/x;}]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=center,axis y line=center,xtick=\empty,ytick=  \empty,xlabel=$x(t)$,
ylabel=$y(t)$,] 
\addplot [red!30!white,name path=f,domain=-3:3, samples=60] {f};

\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

\addplot[red!30!white] fill between[of=f and axis];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How I control that?

Comment: From what I can see, the second plot has a narrower bounding box than the area it occupies.

Comment: Is possible, but I can't see that in code ...

Comment: I just surrounded the `tikzpicture` with `\fbox{...}` and saw what TeX is thinking the bounding box is. Or try switching the pictures, you'll see that the hyperbola overlaps the other one.

Comment: :o I surround the second `tikzpicture` with `\fbox{...}` and the graphic isn't centered ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing `scale=0.71` to `tikzpicture` pass it to the `axis` options. I have also added `ylabel style={anchor=west}` to put y label little up.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{23cm}{15.9cm}
\settrimmedsize{23cm}{15.9cm}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{17.8cm}{11.3cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{2.3cm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{6.4\onelineskip}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{1.18\onelineskip}{\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{4.1\onelineskip}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[lines]

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/area style/.style={%
area cycle list,
area legend,
axis on top,
}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\blindtext

\begin{figure}[b]
%\centering
\subcaptionbox{A cat\label{cat}}{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[scale=0.71,axis equal,axis on top,axis lines=center,enlargelimits=false,xlabel=$x(t)$,ylabel=$y(t)$,xmax=2.5,xmin=-2.2,ymax=2.5,ymin=-2.2,area legend,xtick=\empty,ytick= \empty,
ylabel style={anchor=west} %,legend entries={$\Ran f$}
]
\addplot[draw=blue!30!white,fill=blue!30!white,
domain=-2:2,samples=120] {sqrt(4-x^2)};
%\addlegendimage{fill=blue!30!white,area legend}
%\addlegendentry{$\Ran f$}
\addplot[draw=blue!30!white,fill=blue!30!white,
domain=-2:2,samples=120] {-sqrt(4-x^2)};

\addplot[white,fill,
domain=-1:1,samples=120] {sqrt(1-x^2)};
\addplot[white,fill,
domain=-1:1,samples=120] {-sqrt(1-x^2)};
%\node at (380,170) {$x'(t)$};
%\node at (20,170) {$y'(t)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subcaptionbox{An elephant\label{elephant}}[.51\linewidth]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/declare function={f=1/x;}]
\begin{axis}[scale=0.71,axis x line=center,axis y line=center,xtick=\empty,ytick=  \empty,xlabel=$x(t)$,
ylabel=$y(t)$,,
ylabel style={anchor=west}]
\addplot [red!30!white,name path=f,domain=-3:3, samples=60] {f};

\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

\addplot[red!30!white] fill between[of=f and axis];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]